# How do you show the full directory in Fish when using Bash on Windows?

Tags: windows, bash, fish

I have two questions, really: first, how do I change my prompt so that instead of /m/c/U/D/D... etc it shows /mnt/c/Users/Danny/Documents... i.e. the full path? I'm using Fish on top of Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.

Second, why is it that, despite the fact I've successfully installed the themes on fish, the colors and fonts are still off? Is there some additional setup needed? I tried googling answers to these questions unsuccessfully.

[image: My terminal]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since fish 2.3.0, the `prompt_pwd` function that is usually used to display the pwd in the prompt (among other things, it replaces $HOME with a "~") supports a variable called `fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length` that you can set to whatever you want. In your case it should be "0" or a non-integer value.

I.e.

```
set -g fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length 0
```